# "advocate xxxism" or "advocate for xxxism"? (where xxxism is an ideology, e.g. Marxism, Stalinism, Maoism, Platonism, Communism)

Tags: for

"advocate xxxism" or "advocate for xxxism"? (where xxxism is an ideology, e.g. Marxism, Stalinism, Maoism, Platonism, Communism, Capitalism, Socialism)

Answer (score 2):

The verb ***to advocate*** is normally *transitive*. That's to say it takes an *object* (the thing being endorsed / defended) *without* needing a preposition.

The full OED does specifically mention *intransitive* use - essentially, exactly the same as usual, except that the object takes an explicitly specified preposition (usually ***for***). Note that it's relatively uncommon to include ***for*** if the object is an ***idea / philosophy*** being promoted, but it's quite natural to say things like *He advocated **for** the victims* (or ***...on behalf of*** the victims), where the object is "beneficiaries", rather than "ideas".

---

See [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=advocated%20civil%20rights%2Cadvocated%20for%20civil%20rights%2Cadvocated%20of%20civil%20rights&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cadvocated%20civil%20rights%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cadvocated%20for%20civil%20rights%3B%2Cc0), showing that when ***advocate*** is a *verb* (as in *He advocated [**for**] civil rights*) there's normally no preposition. But see [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=an%20advocate%20for%20civil%20rights%2Can%20advocate%20of%20civil%20rights&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Can%20advocate%20for%20civil%20rights%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Can%20advocate%20of%20civil%20rights%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Can%20advocate%20for%20civil%20rights%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Can%20advocate%20of%20civil%20rights%3B%2Cc0) showing that when it's a *noun* (as in *He is an advocate **for / of** civil rights*), we *do* include a preposition (usually, ***for***).

In short, you *don't* normally want a preposition between (verb) ***advocate*** and ***thing advocated***, but you *do* need one if it's a noun usage, or the object of the verb is a reference to whoever / whatever ***benefits*** (by having their cause advocated).

Answer (score 0):

You can see the definition here:

https://www.dictionary.com/browse/advocate

"Advocate" can be used a verb or a noun.

In the verb sense, you would "advocate xxxism", or "advocate for xxxism".

In the noun sense, to describe something/someone as an advocate, you would use "advocate **of** xxxism".

With regards to the difference between the two verb senses.

> I advocate xxxism.

This sounds (moreso than using "for") like you are suggesting the application of xxxism in a particular situation. E.g.:

> I advocate xxxism, it will solve this in no time.

On the other hand:

> I advocate for xxxism.

This is closer to saying that you advocate **on behalf of** xxxism; it sounds less like you are directly recommending the application of xxxism, and more that you are advocating to further the cause of xxxism. It has a more general feel to it.

With regards to ideologies, I feel the noun form would usually represent the appropriate usage:

> I am an advocate of xxxism.

Answer (score 0):

I would use:

advocate of [some ism or other noun denoting a field]
or

[some ism or other noun denoting a field ] advocate. Making an adjective of a noun is common in English.

For example: **social justice advocate, advocate of social justice or advocate for social justice**

[social justice advocate](http://nagps.org/about-us/committees/social-justice-committee/)

[advocate of social justice and advocate for social justice](https://www.citylightchurchwb.org/blog/post/the-)

Likewise, advocate of Marxism, Marxism advocate or advocate for Marxism

Bear in mind that the use of for implies: on behalf of [some ism or idea], more specifically.

communism, socialism and capitalism are not proper nouns and do not require a capital letter.

- **He advocates for immigrant rights**, is a verb. But **for** does not always require a verb.
- **He is an advocate for human rights.**